# Bluemix -- terminal needs credential in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, terminal, ibm-cloud

Im working on DW001 course, which is related to ibm bluemix. In exercise 5a, the final step is to open a terminal and connect. when i tried doing this, my eclipse is prompting me to enter details as shown in the below image

[image]

what should be the settings that to be made ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a convenience to run command line commands in Eclipse

On unix based machines, this opens up a terminal window inside Eclipse.

On Windows, I recommend you just open up your Command Prompt window. Start -> Run -> cmd

Comment: Thank you :) @ram Vennam